# email body from contents of file per line

Tags: linux, email, postfix-mta

I am trying to bulk email in some tickets for my helpdesk team. I have a text file with "body" content per line. I'd like to be able to email this into our ticket system easily instead of manually creating tickets.

I've tried stuff like:

```
mail -s "Need antivirus installed" ticketsystem@domain.com while read line; do echo -e "$line\n"; done < listofcomputers.txt
```

Unfortunately I'm not using `while; do` inline properly. I'm using Ubuntu with a properly configured `postfix` and `mailutils` installed but I'm open to any suggestions/solutions using the Linux CLI.

Any other solutions or anyone see where I've gone wrong with my current attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while read line
do
  echo "$line" | mail -s "Need antivirus installed" ticketsystem@domain.com
done < listofcomputers.txt
```

I think that does what it appears you want to do.